# caps lock remapping not working in system settings after latest os update

Tags: settings, keyboard, horus

I just installed the latest two Horus updates using the AppCenter, and on rebooting found the System Settings / Keyboard option fo Caps Lock Behavior is not working (nothing happens no matter what it's set to). The other Keyboard options do seem to still work.

Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Actually, the Compose Key option does not appear to be working, either.

Comment: After installing the latest 5 updates and rebooting, these problems have still not been fixed.

Comment: After the latest 17 updates and a reboot, these problems still have NOT been fixed.

Comment: Fortunately, after today's 8 OS updates and a reboot, these settings have started working again -- not right away, but only after opening the Keyboard settings panel and playing with it for a bit. Thank you whoever your are!